# Laplace transform of $f(t)=e^{-Kt^n} $

Tags: laplace-transform

Could someone help me find the Laplace transform of the time funtion $f(t)=e^{-Kt^n} $ where $K$ is real and positive and $0<n<1$ ? Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, I once noticed an example about $F(s)=e^{-s^{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

We have that :
$$
\frac{\Gamma(\omega)}{m^{\omega}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\omega^{-1}}e^{-mn}\;\text{d}x
$$
Now applying the Laplace Transform of $e^{-Kt^{n}}$, we get :
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(e^{-Kt^{n}}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-Kt^{n}}e^{-st}\;\text{d}t
\tag{1}$$
Since :
$$
e^{-Kt^{n}}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-K)^{r}}{r!}t^{nr}
\tag{2}$$
Then by substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get :
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-K)^{r}}{r!}t^{nr}e^{-st}\;\text{d}t
$$
Hence, we get that :
$$
\boxed{F(s)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-K)^{r}}{r!}\frac{\Gamma(1+nr)}{s^{1+nr}}}
$$

**[Note]** : $1+nr>0$ to avoid $\Gamma$ diverging to $\pm\infty$

Comment: Thank you Gauss1860. I tried to get a compact form, but I had not thought of a series expansion

Comment: Indeed this is an interesting problem, where did you obtain it from?

Comment: This function is a part of the Avrami model that is used to model some chemical reaction kinetics. I try  to analyse the frequency response of this model using its Laplace transform.